# Is is possible to package non-standard files in APK without assets?

Tags: android

I am trying to package `/somewhere/lib/python3.x` inside APK's `lib` folder like jniLibs. But it contains `*.py`, `*.pyc` and other files. I have asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332861/how-to-package-pythonhome-files-into-apk), but there is no answer. So this is a general question: do you ever used or developed any plugins that embed non-standard files in APK instead of using `assets`?

Answer (score 1):

How would you access those files?  I mean you could put them in the apk, an apk is just a zip file.  But the system won't unpack them for you, and at runtime you won't be able to access the apk file itself (installation unzips your file and deletes the apk).  You might be able to fool it into doing so by putting it with the jni libs and hoping it doesn't look at extention, but it seem like a bad idea.

However its not uncommon for an app to take its assets and write them to the filesystem on first boot.  In fact its fairly common to do this with updatable assets (you'd then just download new versions on top of them, but you can use the old versions to not need an immediate network connection).  This would probably work for you.  Just make your initial activity a splash screen, and have it do the copy from assets to files in the background while the splash is up.

Comment: Thank you very much for the notification that the apk wouldn't be unzipped during installation. Then I need to add a bunch of flavors to bundle them in assets and extract them during the first boot and upgrading. BTW, I have tried to put them inside jniLibs with no lucky :-( . It saves me a whole year of time.

Comment: Actually, it is an industrial product with a customized Android system. Although I could customize the PackageInstaller to unzip the files, I think it is waste of time.